# Oracle Business Intelligence 12c Error 500

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence

I have installed Oracle Business Intelligence. 
I try connect to BI Analytics servies. 
I can open link http://hostname:8502/analytics/ and see page with login name and password. Then I try log in and after that i get error:

**Error 500--Internal Server Error
From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
10.5.1 500 Internal Server Error
The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.**

What can be the reason?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the server. Depending on the web server, check the server log files to get more information about the reason and [edit] your question afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the underlying problem was that BI services were not up and running. To be more specific, "BI Presentation Services" looks like the required one to show the dashboard after login.

You can execute $ORACLE_HOME\user_projects\domains\bi\bitools\bin\start.cmd to start all BI services as specified at http://aditya-kaushal.blogspot.cz/2015/11/obiee12-how-to-start-and-stop-bi.html. In fact, that script also verifies if  BI and Admin domains are running as well.